# Updating a table to create unique ids in from a substring in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table1 with following columns and example of data:

```
id, condition1, condition2, condition3, target_id
1, Westminster, Abbey Road, NW1 1FS, null
2, Westminster, Abbey Road, NW1 1FG, null
3, Westminster, China Road, NW1 1FG, null
4, Wandsworth, China Road, SE5 3LG, null
5, Wandsworth, China Road, SE5 3LS, null
```

Intended result for the target_id would be:

```
 id, condition1, condition2, condition3, target_id
1, Westminster, Abbey Road, NW1 1FS, 1
2, Westminster, Abbey Road, NW1 1FG, 1
3, Westminster, China Road, NW1 1FG, 2
4, Wandsworth, China Road, SE5 3LG, 3
5, Wandsworth, China Road, SE5 3LS, 3
```

I'm trying to update target_id with a unique identity based on grouping condition1, condition2 and first characters of condition3

Essentially what I'm trying to do I think looks something like

```
update table1 set target_id = (select "unique id" from table1 group by condition1, condition2, left(condition3 ,5)
```

The goal then would be for every id, I would have a target_id which matches its set of characteristics from the 3 condition columns. How to achieve this?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: yes, [it is](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.9.7.2.2.13.1.1)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . You are right.  Once upon a time I defined it locally so I could use it -- that must have been pre-9.1, because it appears to be there since then.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I've updated the op

Answer (score 0):

Your question suggests that you want a query like this:

```
update table1 t1
    set target_id = (select "unique id"
                     from table1 tt1
                     where tt1.condition1 = t1.condition1 and
                           tt1.condition2 = t1.condition2 and
                           left(tt1.condition3, 5) = left(t1.condition3, 5)
                    );
```

However, this will likely return an error of the sort "subquery returns more than one row".  To fix that, you need a `limit 1` or aggregation function.  Something like:

```
update table1 t1
    set target_id = (select max("unique id")
                     from table1 tt1
                     where tt1.condition1 = t1.condition1 and
                           tt1.condition2 = t1.condition2 and
                           left(tt1.condition3, 5) = left(t1.condition3, 5)
                    );
```

EDIT:

If you just want to enumerate things, you can use `dense_rank()`:

```
update table1 t1
    set target_id = tt1.seqnum
    from (select t1.*,
                 dense_rank() over (order by condition1, condition2, left(condition3, 5)) as seqnum
          from table1 t1
         ) tt1
    where tt1.id = t1.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Apologies if I failed to explain but "unique id" does not exist, it was what I was trying to generate

Comment: I wasn't able to finish query yday because I think it wasn't using any of the indexes on the table. When I tried explain it did not show as using any of the indexes conditions. I have indexes on all 3 columns. Do i need some kind of complex index?