# Indexing for dense_rank query in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

So been trying to run a query on a big table but it's taking more than a day to finish, when I put explain at the beginning and went through the result, it did not appear as using an index

The query was here on this question  [Updating a table to create unique ids in from a substring in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59984975/updating-a-table-to-create-unique-ids-in-from-a-substring-in-postgresql?noredirect=1#comment106083756_59984975)

```
update table1 t1
set target_id = tt1.seqnum
from (select t1.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by condition1, condition2, left(condition3, 5)) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) tt1
where tt1.id = t1.id;
```

Would a 3 column index make this query use an index? OR any other way to optimise this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need an index on `id`.  That is probably there because it should be a primary key.

Then, Postgres would probably use an index on `(condition1, condition2, left(condition3, 5))` for the `dense_rank()`.  You might want to test to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the presence of the `LEFT` function in the `ORDER BY` clause of `DENSE_RANK` should preclude the chance to use any index there.  I suggest the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON table1 (condition1, condition2, condition3);
```

There is no real benefit to using `LEFT(condition3, 5)`, so I suggest calling `DENSE_RANK` as:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY condition1, condition2, condition3)
```

The above version should be *sargable*, and the index suggested should be usable.